# make: function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, makefile

I am learning Go lang by this video tutorial https://youtu.be/LOn1GUsjOF4?t=163 . My environment: Windows 11 x64, Visual Studio Code 1.75.1 (latest), Go v1.20.1 (latest).

File `main.go`

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("We good")
}
```

File `go.mod`

```
module newsfeeder

go 1.20
```

File `makefile`

```
dev:
    go run main.go
```

[image]

```golang
PS D:\temp2023_02_24\newfeeder> go mod init newsfeeder
go: creating new go.mod: module newsfeeder
go: to add module requirements and sums:
        go mod tidy
PS D:\temp2023_02_24\newfeeder> go run .\main.go
hi
PS D:\temp2023_02_24\newfeeder> go run .\main.go
hi
PS D:\temp2023_02_24\newfeeder> go run .\main.go
function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ make dev
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (make:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS D:\temp2023_02_24\newfeeder>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You didn't provde the whole error message. why did you try to censor part of it out in your screenshot and omit it from your text quotation?

Comment: This tutorial seems to promote bad habits like using makefiles and worse: using file name arguments to go run. Stop trying to learn from bad resources.

Answer (score 0):

The [`ms-vscode.makefile-tools`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.makefile-tools) extension does not come with an installation of the `make` program.

See [this quote from `bobrow`, one of the maintainers of the extension on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-makefile-tools/issues/404#issuecomment-1438845044):

> The extension does not install `make`. It is usually installed with your compiler (in the same folder). It doesn't have a standalone installer which is why we don't provide instructions on how to get it.

<sup>For your learning purposes, all I did to find that GitHub issue (where the issue ticket raiser pretty much has the same problem as you- or at least- has the same error message as you), is google "`"function, script file, or operable program" site:github.com/Microsoft/vscode-makefile-tools/issues`".</sup>

You need to make sure your either already have it installed with your (C or C++) compiler or install it yourself, and make sure that it is visible in the `PATH` environment variable when you run VS Code (which usually means adding the directory containing the executable to your system path, which will usually be done for you when running installers or installing things via package-management systems). Since in your case you are on Windows, and you are using Makefiles for Go programming (interesting / eyebrow raiser), you probably don't have the `make` program installed yet. As others have said, you can install it from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/postdownload, or from a package manager like Chocolatey (see https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/make).

Answer (score 0):

go to https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/postdownload , download, install

[image]

Set environment PATH , run "C:\MinGW\bin\mingw-get.exe"

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1265]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\admin>cd C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
The directory name is invalid.

C:\Users\admin>cd D:\temp2023_02_24\newfeeder

C:\Users\admin>cd /d D:\temp2023_02_24\newfeeder

D:\temp2023_02_24\newfeeder>mingw32-make
go run main.go
We good

D:\temp2023_02_24\newfeeder>
```